# StackOverflowError in recursive binary search in file in java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, binary-search, random-access

The `filepointer` gets stuck at a point resulting in a `StackOverflowError`. Can you point me to what exactly is wrong here? The error exactly is: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

I am doing a seek to find the location as record width is not fixed.

Here is the piece of code:

```
private static void binarySearch(RandomAccessFile raf, String searchvalue, Long low, Long high) throws IOException
{
    Long middle = (low + high) / 2;
    Long mreal = null;
    if(low > raf.length() -1 || high > raf.length()-1 || low >= high) {
        System.out.println("Element not found:");   return ;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(long filePointer = middle; filePointer != -1; filePointer--) {
        raf.seek(filePointer);
        int readByte = raf.readByte();
        if(readByte == 0xA) {
            break;
        }

        sb.append((char)readByte);
    }

    String lastLine = sb.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(lastLine);

    mreal = raf.getFilePointer();
    String str = raf.readLine();
    System.out.println(str);

    String values[] = str.split("\t",-1);
    int compared = searchvalue.compareTo(values[fieldindex]);
    System.out.println(fieldindex);

    if(compared == 0) {
        System.out.println("Value found. The other details:");
        for(int i=0; i < values.length;i++)
        System.out.print("\t" +  values[i]);
        return;
    } else if(compared < 0)
        binarySearch(raf,searchvalue,low,mreal-1);
    else if(compared > 0)
        binarySearch(raf,searchvalue,mreal,high);
}
```

Stack trace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
>at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.<init>(Pattern.java:2993)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.<init>(Pattern.java:3332)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.<init>(Pattern.java:3332)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.<init>(Pattern.java:3363)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.<init>(Pattern.java:3363)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern$Single.<init>(Pattern.java:3391)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.newSingle(Pattern.java:2951)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1985)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1885)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    >at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    >at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow error is when you run into an infinite loop or condition and the program cannot allocate more memory onto stack for it.

Comment: Try debugger. Or write small tests to smaller functionality. In current form, question is 'too localised'

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer : Added the stack trace

Comment: Oh, got it. The whole stack trace cannot be given - it has no end.

Comment: how long is str? try change negative limit to positive in String values[] = str.split("\t",-1);

Comment: Post enough of the stack trace for us to see where it starts repeating. Without that, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(compared > 0)
    binarySearch(raf,searchvalue,mreal,high);
```

That should be mreal + 1.

Also, recursion is overkill for binary search.... typically a loop is faster.

Rolf

EDIT:====

OK, so it still does not work. It's because I was only partly right. I only looked at the code for a moment and saw the problem, but then I fixed it with the wrong value.

Instead of adding 1, you should be adding the number of characters in the string that you compared to, plus the line-termination (if any - it may be the last line...).

What this whole thing tells me is that this is probably homework... and an exercise in recursion and a study of binary search.

Without doing the homework for you, I will spend a moment criticising your code.

Binary search is supposed to find the mid-point, and then, if the mid-point matches, return it, if it's bigger than the search, then search before the mid point, otherwise search after the mid-point.

Your code is getting the mid-point 'right', and the 'before' right, but it's not searching 'after'... because you are not calculating the 'after' part right.. You need to be 'after' the whole string, not just after the first character. Fix it. Remember, using readLine() means that you do not know the line terminator (is it '\r\n' or just '\n'?). I recommend using a loop after the 'middle' point, and then walking forward yourself until you get to another \n and then using that (+1) to calculate the position of the 'after' search if you need it.

Some other comments....

- Do not use 'autoboxing'. Use long primitives instead of Long objects.
- Why call getFilePointer() when the value it returns is already known in the variable 'filepointer'.
- When calculating the 'middle', use low + high >>> 1 .... it will impress your lecturer and you can say you know why after you read this: http://googleresearch.blogspot.ca/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html
- While you are reading that, you can figure out why doing binary search in a loop is better than doing it in recursion.
- if you *do* use recursion, you should be setting your parameters to 'final', because that leaves a smaller footprint on the stack, and you can go 'deeper'.
- if you *do* use recursion, then you should minimize the objects you create in your method... like StringBuilders....

Rolf

Comment: I just changed it. But same problem.

Comment: One quick question: when I do str = raf.readLine();, after this statement, where does the file pointer point to? the end of the current line or the beginning of the new line?

Comment: Good question. The documentation does not emphatically state one way or another. It would make sense though that the filepointer will be pointing to the first character *after* the line terminator (so the next readLine() would work).